# Creating a scrollable window without Layouts

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to achieve something what, I thought, would be a super easy thing to do. But for some reason QtDesigner is driving me crazy, it simply won't work...

I created a GUI and freely arranged different elements in the window, without layout or anything like that. At some point there were to many elements, so all I wanted to to, was to make it scrollable up and down, to see all elements.

So I added a ScrollArea in QtDesigner and added all elements as children of this ScrollArea (which btw also was a pain in the ass, because apparently drag and drop in the Object viewer is not a thing, and editing the .ui file by hand, is also not allowed... great).

So the result I have now is the following:

- before resize - no scrollbar, elements at bottom inaccessible

[image]

- resized vertically - some stuff still snapped off at the bottom

[image]

So as you see, although I created a ScrollArea... There is no scroll area. So I googled a little bit and found out that you can add layouts to your scrollarea, and yey, finally, a scroll bar! But how in this world am I supposed to arrange the elements in the way you see in the screenshots, with layouts. They are so super restrictive.

How am I supposed to simply get a vertical scrollbar, without this restrictive layout stuff?!

Here is how my object viewer looks

[image]

And here is what is called upon GUI creation:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
//setCentralWidget(ui->scrollArea);
//ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
```

I tried it with, and without the commented lines. No scrollbar, no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to fix it:

In Qt Designer:

- Select `QScrollArea` object.
- Uncheck the `QScrollArea` properties `widgetResizable`.

In C++:

```
// If you want to set `widgetResizable` programmaticly
ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false); // Optional if you did it in Qt Designer
ui->scrollArea->widget()->adjustSize();
```